# cant read cookie in nextjs ssr

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cookies, next.js

I have a problem with read a cookie in my browser.. here's my code

````
const dataA = authService.isLogin();

useEffect(() => {
  if (dataA) {
     router.push("/");
  }
}, [dataA]); ```

the dataA is get a cookie value from my browser.. but thats not working.. it caused my router.push not redirect to the page

how can i solve it ?
````

Comment: Where is the code to read the cookie? Please add that.

Comment: export function getCookie(cname) {
  if (typeof document === "undefined") return;
  let name = cname + "=";
  let decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
  let ca = decodedCookie.split(";");
  for (let i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
    let c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0) == " ") {
      c = c.substring(1);
    }
    if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
      return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
    }
  }
  return "";
} @SurjeetBhadauriya

Answer (score 1):

You should move `dataA` into useEffect hook because `dataA` run in SSR not browser so that can't read cookie from browser. Try like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const dataA = authService.isLogin();
  if (dataA) {
     router.push("/");
  }
}, [dataA]);
```